# What was the relationship between Isa (A.S) and Yahya (A.S)?

Tags: hadith, history, prophet-isa

What was the relationship between Isa (A.S) and Yahya (A.S).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were cousins, as their mothers were sisters.

> فلما خلصت، فإذا يحيى وعيسى **وهما ابنا خالة**
>
> When we reached over the second heaven, I saw Yahya (i.e. John) and Jesus **who were maternal cousins.**
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari , كتاب أحاديث الأنبياء](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/101)</sup>

> وكان زكريا نبي ذلك الزمان زوج أخت مريم أشياع في قول الجمهور وقيل زوج خالتها أشياع
>
> Zechariah was the husband of the sister of Maryam, her name was Eshya', this is the saying of the majority. And one saying is that Zechariah was the husband of the aunt of Maryam and her name was Eshya'
>
> <sup>—[Al-Bidaya wa'l-Nihaya](https://shamela.ws/book/8376/462#p1)</sup>